# Which side of the capacitor is at higher potential?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

Our physics teacher gave us a simple problem in our class related to the diagram below.

The current increases at the rate $4 {\rm As^{-1}}$ and we are to find charge on the capacitor when current is $2$ ${\rm A}$.

[image]

Using KVL (Faraday's Law technically) we can solve for the charge $Q$ on the capacitor,

$$-V_2+IR_1 + L_1\frac{dI}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C_2} = 0 \\ \Rightarrow -4 + 2 +1\times(4) + \frac{Q}{3\mu}=0 \\ \Rightarrow Q=-6\times {10}^{-6} {\rm C}$$

My doubt is why the negative sign?

As far as I understand, the negative sign means is that the upper plate has negative charge. So point B is at higher potential than A. But is that possible? If I am incorrect, then what is actually happening here? Is it because an inductor is present? Please explain.

My question can be boiled down to which side of the capacitor is at higher potential in the given circuit? Why?

This point was noticed by our teacher, who just did a hand-wave and I am not convinced by his arguments.

Comment: Whether or not you get a minus sign depends on what you used when you "form the equation".    Without knowing that, we can't help.  Also, there's no "left" and "right"  for the capacitor in your diagram.  It's "up" and "down", and it's possible that that confusion is messing up your analysis.

Comment: @garyp I have appropriately edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: The sign depends on how you pick up the direction of the current and the way you go around the loop when using KVL.

Comment: @nasu I am not sure I understand "how you pick up the direction of the current". Isn't the direction of the current fixed? And isn't KVL independent of the direction we travel?

Comment: @AlphaDelta The direction that the current flows the through the circuit is what it is, but you can take your KVL loop in either direction.  If you choose the direction of the current, it will "come out" of the equation with a + sign.  If you choose the other direction, it will come out with a - sign. In this case, you knew the current direction, but in a more general case you might be solving for it and not know a priori which way it goes. Similar comment on signs for other quantities.

Comment: Also, you should keep the units in the calculation.  Presumably your result is in C?

Comment: @Brick I had assumed the current to be ACW. So does it mean that the current is CW? If yes, then who is providing the EMF for the current to run CW? Is it the inductor?

Comment: I meant units all the way through, not jammed onto the end.  It doesn't matter which way you assumed the current goes, that's the whole point. If you apply the equations properly, they will tell you the physical direction.

Comment: @AlphaDelta In your equation you wrote +Q/C. This means you assumed some "direction" for the potential drop across the capacitor. You got minus so this means you assumed wrong.

Comment: @nasu Yes. I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the teacher specified 2A?  I simulated this circuit and the peak current i'm getting is just under 7mA.

Comment: @relayman357 Yes I am sure. The problem was to just introduce us to the topic. So I am sure it was not in any way rigorous.